# Git bash for windows runs wrong version of python using "python" command

Tags: shell, command, environment-variables, git-bash

I uninstalled python 2.7 and replaced it with python 3 but in git bash the `python` command is still trying to use the 2.7 version. How do I fix it?

### Details

`python --version` returns `Python 2.7.10` in bash shell but in command prompt it returns `Python 3.6.0`.

`whereis python` returns

```
python: 
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python2.7-config 
/usr/lib/python2.6 
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/usr/include/python2.7 
/cygdrive/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python3.dll 
/cygdrive/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python36.dll 
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

which is the same as command prompt.

My `$PATH` is

```
/c/Users/YANG/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/bin
/c/Users/YANG/bin
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
/c/WINDOWS/system32
/c/WINDOWS
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static
/c/cygwin64/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin
/cmd
/c/Program Files/nodejs
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/atom/bin
/c/xampp/php
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin
/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Composer/vendor/bin
/c/Users/YANG/AppData/Roaming/npm
/usr/bin/vendor_perl
/usr/bin/core_perl
```

`$ where python` returns

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\python
C:\Users\YANG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

which is the same as command prompt.

`$ which python` returns

```
/c/cygwin64/bin/python
```

while command prompt returns

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
python3 program.py
```

instead of

```
python program.py
```

you can set an alias for bash to use python3 in place of python, but just using python3 works fine.

Comment: `python3` didn't work but setting `python` to be an alias for `python.exe` did work. Thanks.